# SVG width and height when inserted in HTML as text

Tags: html, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/g10qjbLa/

Could you tell me why the width of this heml element is ~133?

I would like it to be 100px (I have stipulated width and height):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 2447.6 2452.5" viewBox="0 0 2447.6 2452.5" width="100pt" height="100pt">
```

[image]

Comment: If you want it to be 100px then just make it 100px and not 100pt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote PT instead PX:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 2447.6 2452.5" viewBox="0 0 2447.6 2452.5" width="100pt" height="100pt">`

needs to be : `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 2447.6 2452.5" viewBox="0 0 2447.6 2452.5" width="100px" height="100px">`

Comment: note: ``enable-background`` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/enable-background